# Merge object in jquery but return unwanted data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had this codes to fetch all records in the grid and store into object `(items)` also an additional object called `(data)`. Then I merge these 2 object. But the output return like the image below. How to remove those `0[itemID_0]: LA1` so it can only become `itemID_0: LA1`? Appreciate your help here.

[image]

```js
update: {
  url:  "./getRecipe.php",
  type: "POST",
  data :function() {

    var gridDataArray = $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    var items = [];
    for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray.length; i++ ) {    
      items.push({
      ["itemID_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemID'],
      ["itemQty_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemQuantity'],
      ["itemPrice_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemPrice']
      })                 
    };
    console.log(items);

    var data = { 
      method: "editRecipe",
      this_propertyID : $('#thisPropertyID').val(),
    };

    var x = {... data, ... items};
    return x;
  },                         
},
.....
```

Comment: `items` is an array of objects, not a single object.

Comment: @Barmar how to convert it to a single object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is an array of objects, you just want a single object. So just assign to the properties rather than using `.push()`.

```
update: {
  url:  "./getRecipe.php",
  type: "POST",
  data :function() {

    var gridDataArray = $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    var items = { 
      method: "editRecipe",
      this_propertyID : $('#thisPropertyID').val(),
    };
    for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray.length; i++ ) {    
      items["itemID_" + i] = gridDataArray[i]['itemID'];
      items["itemQty_" + i] = gridDataArray[i]['itemQuantity'];
      items["itemPrice_" + i] = gridDataArray[i]['itemPrice'];                
    }
    console.log(items);

    return items;
  },                         
},
```

Comment: u're amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you question correctly and you need to merge object with array you have to iterate over array and merge each array item with object, in the result all array items will be inside you `x` object. So instead of this:

```
var x = {... data, ... items};
```

just do next:

```
var x = items.reduce((obj, item) => {
  return {
    ...obj,
    ...item
  }
}, { ...data });
```